# How to count how many times a dictionary element takes a specific value

Tags: python

I have a dictionary named "enron_data". In the dictionary, each key has a variable named "poi". I would like to count how many of the keys have poi=1. Like `enron_data[person_name]["poi"]==1.` Dictionary keys are some names and there are 146 names. I want to count how many of them have poi variable equal to one. Thank a lot.

Comment: Please post the input data.

Comment: You are telling what is the solution , just try a loop and iterate through dictionary and check the condition , if it met increase some counter.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The input data is a material from an udacity project. I tried to iterate it but I did not how to it for a dictionary. Because the keys are not integers, instead they are strings. I tried to enumerate the dictionary to access the correct elements of each key in each iteration but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an sum the equality checks for the entire dictionary.  This works because `True == 1` and `False == 0`

```
sum(v.get("poi", 0) == 1 for v in enron_data.values())
```

Comment: I found the answer. here it is the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa. but actually was looking how to use the for structure you pointed above. It works. Thanks a lot